# Does the tense change when we convert between active and passive voice?

Tags: tense, passive-voice, active-voice

Here are some examples I know of:

**Present:**

- The magic is performed on stage by the magician
- The magician performs the magic on stage.

**Past:**

- Chester kicked the ball.
- The ball was kicked by Chester.

I want to confirm that in general when we convert between passive and active voice, does the tense ever change?

Answer (score 2):

No. Tense and active or passive voice are two different things. I think your understanding is fine.

The magician performed the magic. Active

The magic was performed by the magician. Passive